# IQueryable<T> to return a single record

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, iqueryable

I am using EF Core and am attempting to create a query provider which accepts any type and a single value. I then want to run a query to return the `FirstOrDefault` of the passed in items which have the selected property set to the passed in value. something similar to this:

```
public class TagPicker<T>
{
    public IQueryable<T> Pick(IQueryable<T> source, string column, string filter)
    {
        T result = source.FirstOrDefault(r => r.column == value);

        if (result is null)
        {
            return new T { column = filter };
        }
        else {
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

I have several types which will need this type of query performed. I am trying to avoid having to create duplicates of this type of query for each type.

Any ideas?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this code? This looks like an attempt to replicate `Where()` or `FirstOrDefault(predicate)`, except it doesn't work. You can't create queries that can't be mapped to SQL in the first place. The `where` clause in the query compares two *string* instead of a column and a value.

Comment: Not sure why you need this, can't you just use the predicate filter that `FirstOrDefault` has? For example `source.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value = 4)`

Comment: BTW both `Where()` and `FirstOrDefault` accept any type and any predicate - expression actually. You can store the lambda expression in a variable and pass it to `Where()` or `FirstOrDefaultAsync`, so there's no reason to try and construct your own `FirstOrDefaultAsync`

Comment: If you want to return a `IQueryable<>` (not sure if it is an intelligent thing), there is the `.Take(1)` to return 0...1 elements.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I updated my question with a bit more information

Comment: @user3779856 you didn't add any more information, just repeated that you want what's essentially `FirstOrDefaultAsync`. *Why* can't you just use it? Why would you create duplicates when `FirstOrDefaultAsync` can take a lambda as a paremeter? `r => r.collumn == value` is a **value** that can be stored in a variable and passed as a parameter.

Comment: Is our `column` coming from somewhere external as a string or do you just have methods that need certain columns? Basically does column have to be a string or could it be something else?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Look at its code... `column` (technically `collumn`) is a `string`. He is trying to do Dynamic Linq. On failure he wants to create a new default object that has the property with the name contained in `collumn` assigned with the value `filter`.

Comment: @xanatos which can't be translated to SQL. The dynamic part usually *isn't* necessary because one can pass a lambda. Replacing the null with a default object on the other hand is as easy as `?? new Whatever()` after the results were returned from the database

Comment: @xanatos If I tried to guess the actual purpose of this code though, I'd say it tries to do two things - find a matching tag and when that fails, create a new one. One of these things is a SQL query. The other is post-processing of the query results. Why *column* though? That is a third thing - multiple columns that map to the same entity type. That's something that should be handled by *mapping* either during DbContext configuration or with attributes.

Comment: If the entity properties had the same name, the entities could implement the same interface and allow a simpler `whateverTaggedContext.FirstOrDefault(it=>it.Tag==value) ?? new Whatever(value)`. The mapping would take care to map the `Tag` property to whatever the table field is called

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The important part of what I am trying to accomplish is the logic that is performed after the FirstOrDefault, which either returns the found record or creates a new object as xanatos stated. I would like to avoid having to write out the logic for each type that uses it. I'm new to all this EF stuff , I'm not sure what you mean by "Replacing the null with a default object on the other hand is as easy as ?? new Whatever()"... Perhaps this is what I am looking for, could you provide an example or a link?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is probably wrong... As Panagiotis wrote you could pass a lambda expression to the `Pick` method. But I'll try to make **your** code working. You probably have a [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem. The right solution would be to comprehend what is the Y problem and what is the Y solution. I will instead give the solution of the X problem.

Now, what you are trying to do (putting a column name in a `string`) is called Dynamic Linq. We (where "we" are a big group of C# programmers) try to not use it, because it isn't very "safe", because keeping name of columns inside of `string`s make the code difficult to refactor... But still there is a niche of situations where this is necessary. There are various libraries in .NET to do Dynamic Linq. The one that is currently being developed is [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core). It has a very practical 
 [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/).

Example of code:

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;

public static class TagPicker
{
    public static T Pick<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string column, string filter) where T : class, new()
    {
        // Dynamic Linq supports query in the form *columnname = @0*,
        // where @0 is the first parameter (and @1 the second and so on)
        T result = source.FirstOrDefault(column + " = @0", filter);

        if (result is null)
        {
            // We use reflection to find the column *column* and
            // set its value to *filter*. Note that we don't try
            // to do a cast, so *column* must be of type *string*
            result = new T();
            typeof(T).GetProperty(column).SetValue(result, filter);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

and then use it like:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var result = context.Products.Pick("ProductName", "Foo");
}
```

Now... Out of curiousity, what probably Panagiotis proposed:

```
public static T Pick<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, string>> column, string filter) where T : class, new()
{
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> columnFilter = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Equal(column.Body, Expression.Constant(filter)), column.Parameters);

    T result = source.FirstOrDefault(columnFilter);

    if (result is null)
    {
        result = new T();
        Expression<Action<T>> assign = Expression.Lambda<Action<T>>(Expression.Assign(column.Body, Expression.Constant(filter)), column.Parameters);

        // If you can't compile with the true because you are using an old .NET, remove it
        Action<T> assignCompiled = assign.Compile(true);
        assignCompiled(result);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Use it like:

```
var result = context.Products.Pick(x => x.ProductName, "Foo2");
```

Note that now `x.ProductName` isn't anymore a `string`, it is a lambda expression, so it is validated by the compiler. You could have:

```
Expression<Func<Product, string>> selector;

if (somecondition)
{
    selector = x => x.ProductName;
}
else
{
    selector = x => x.UnitName;
}

var result2 = context.Products.Pick(selector, "Foo2");
```

or in general save the selectors in some variable/select the right selector in any way.

Comment: While this does work. I like the simplicity of  Panagiotis Kanavos comment. whateverTaggedContext.FirstOrDefault(it=>it.Tag==value) ?? new Whatever(value)  I know his response was probably obvious, but hey... I'm new at this.

Answer (score 0):

@PanagiotisKanavos commented a simple solution for doing this. Here it is slightly modified:

```
Object.Foo = context.Foos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Property == form.Value) ?? new Foo { Property = form.Value };
```

Hope this helps someone